# readonly data view (not copy) of attribute subset

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a readonly view (not a copy) of my data for selected attributes. I understand that this is possible to solve with a descriptor / or property but so far I could not figure out how.

In case there is a better way / pattern to solve this I would be happy to learn about it.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


class View:
    def __init__(self, data, attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.data = data
        for a in attributes:
            #setattr(self, a, lambda: getattr(data, a))
            setattr(self, a, property(lambda: getattr(data, a)))


    #@property
    #def b(self):
    #    return self.data.b

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.attributes:
            return getattr(self.data, item)
        raise AttributeError("can't get attribute")

def test_view():
    data = Data(1, 2, 3)

    mydata = View(data, ['b', 'c'])  # but not a!
    assert mydata.b == 2

    data.b = 9
    assert mydata.b == 9

    with pytest.raises(AttributeError, match="can't set attribute"):
        mydata.b = 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that this is possible to solve with a descriptor / or property but so far I could not figure out how.

That's incorrect, actually.

Descriptors only work when found *on the class*, not on instances (properties are a type of descriptor so are no different here). Because your views define attributes *as instance data*, you can't generate properties for those attributes and stick them on your `View` instance. So `setattr(self, a, property(lambda: getattr(data, a)))` doesn't work, no.

This is not a problem to be solved with descriptors. Stick with `__getattr__` doing the lookups, and a corresponding `__setattr__` method to prevent adding attributes to the view:

```
class View:
    def __init__(self, source, *attrs):
        self._attrs = set(attrs)
        self._source = source

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._attrs:
            return getattr(self._source, name)
        raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object has no attribute {name!r}")

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # special case setting self._attrs, as it may not yet exist
        if name == "_attrs" or name not in self._attrs:
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")

    def __dir__(self):
        return self._attrs
```

I made a few more alterations here. The attributes are stored as a set so testing if a name is part of the attributes forming the view we can do so efficiently. I also implemented [`__dir__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__) so `dir(mydata)` returns the available attributes.

Note that I also altered the API *slightly* there, making `View()` take an arbitrary number of arguments to define the attribute names. This would make your test look like this:

```
data = Data(1, 2, 3)

mydata = View(data, 'b', 'c')  # but not a!
assert mydata.b == 2

data.b = 9
assert mydata.b == 9

with pytest.raises(AttributeError, match="can't set attribute"):
    mydata.b = 10
```

In fact, there is no way you can generate descriptors on the fly for this, even using a metaclass, as attribute lookups for an instance do not consult `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` on the metaclass (it's an optimization, see [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)). Only `__getattributes__` or `__getattr__` defined on the class remain as hook points, and generating a property object in either of those methods just to bind them is just more indirection than is needed here.

If you are creating a lot of these `View` objects, you probably do want to use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). If you use this, no `__dict__` descriptor is created for your class, and so instances don't have arbitrary attributes. Instead, you name each attribute it *can* have, and Python will create special descriptors for those and reserve space for their values. Because the `__dict__` dictionaries required to give instances arbitrary attributes take more memory space than the fixed space reserved for a known number of attributes, this saves memory. It also has the side effect you can't add any new attributes to your `View` instances, making the `__setattr__` method unnecessary:

```
class View:
   __slots__ = ("_attrs", "_source")

   def __init__(self, source, *attrs):
       self._attrs = set(attrs)
       self._source = source

   def __getattr__(self, name):
       if name in self._attrs:
           return getattr(self._source, name)
       raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object has no attribute {name!r}")

   def __dir__(self):
       return self._attrs
```

However, without a `__setattr__` the message on the `AttributeError` thrown when you try to set attributes does change somewhat:

```
>>> mydata.b = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'b'
```

so you may want to keep it anyway.

Comment: Thank you Martijn for your insightful and well written answer. I had an inkling that I had found a good usecase for descriptors but from your answer it is clearly not the case. My first impression about the solution using \__slots__ is clean and efficient. From your answer I take that there are also cases that warrant use of the first solution, or is it just a matter of personal preference? My Python-Zen is a bit hesitant to tell me the one obvious way. Please advice.

Comment: @mark: personally, I'd use the one with `__slots__`. It's just a little bit more advanced, using slots requires that you pay attention when using inheritance (all classes must use `__slots__` or you'll lose the benefits), so it's not something I advice that often.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what exactly you want to happen.  Some options include

- `my_view.a = 1` throws an exception, but `my_view.increment_myself()` does not.  That is, you trust all of the side effects of all of your functions.
- `x = my_view.a` works because `a` was in your "whitelist" of readable attributes when you defined the class. `my_view.increment_myself()` throws an exception because it was not.
- `my_view.newvar = 1` can throw and exception or just silently add a new variable to the view that does not propagate to the underlying model.

The best practice is to explicitly create your proxy from a utility function:

```
class Employee():
   def __init__(self, name): ...
EmployeeViewer = create_view(Employee, 'name department format_mailer')
```

The proxy keeps a reference to the original, only a few bytes.  Simply overwriting the `__getattr__` handles most of your problems.  If you truly want to stop `my_view.newvar = 1`, you need to use your own `__new__` to prevent the class from getting a `__dict__`; look how `slots` are implemented.

You should be thinking carefully about why you want this code.  If you are not trusting an adversary, you need a separate process or at least sandboxing.  If you seek clarity and using types to avoid conflicts in a large project, you can simply put most code in `EmployeeView` class, but keep the `save` functions in a `EmployeeWritable` subclass.

Keep designing!  Keep notes.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to make the new class immutable you could simply add the attributes to `__dict__` and then override `__setattr__`

```py
class View(object):

    def __init__(self, data, attributes):

        for a in attributes:
            self.__dict__[a] = getattr(data, a)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
```

```
In [8]: data = Data(1,2,3)

In [9]: view = View(data, ['b', 'c'])

In [10]: view == data
Out[10]: False

In [11]: data.b = 9

In [12]: view.b
Out[12]: 2

In [13]: view.b = 9
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5ea4b75d3c75> in <module>
----> 1 view.b = 9

<ipython-input-2-58e184f9b1ee> in __setattr__(self, name, value)
      7
      8     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
----> 9         raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
     10

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Side note, your `assert mydata.b == 9` above should not pass in any case. I assume that was meant to read `assert mydata.b == 2` to prove that `assert data != mydata` is `True`

Now, if your goal is to allow new properties to be set, but keep the initial copied values immutable then that's a more complex problem.

Lastly, if you google around for 'immutable python class' you will see that there's no real pattern (and lots of discussion as to whether this is even possible or a good idea).

### Two other options

You may also look into [attr](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html) and `frozen=True` to see if that provides what you're looking for. Although, with your requirement of a dynamic parameter set, I don't think this will work.

You might also consider making your class a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) since it has no class methods. In this case, you'd do something like:

```py
def make_immutable(class_name, attributes):
    field_names = ' '.join(attributes)
    values = {x:getattr(class_name, x) for x in class_name.__dict__ if x in attributes}
    n_tuple = namedtuple('View', field_names)
    return n_tuple(**values)
```

```py
mydata = make_immutable(data, ['b', 'c'])
```

```
In [40]: mydata = make_immutable(data, ['b', 'c'])

In [41]: mydata.a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f64a0775dcb3> in <module>
----> 1 mydata.a

AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'a'

In [42]: mydata.b
Out[42]: 2

In [43]: mydata.b = 10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-08e3c6ebc58b> in <module>
----> 1 mydata.b = 10

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution is an immutable copy. As I stated in my lengthy introduction: "I want a readonly view (not a copy)". So the assert mydata.b == 9 statement MUST pass in every case.

Comment: Oh... well, I'm not sure if this can even be done, then (yes, I just challenged the internet...). I'm thinking the issue is you're attempting to reference an instance attribute/property in another instance. Something akin to a pointer/reference in C.  This gets way over my head but, check out this article. About halfway down when they talk about namespaces https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes

Comment: You misunderstood what is meant by a *view*. The attributes on `mydata` are meant to be *proxies*, accessing them should really access `data.<attributename>`. This is why the OP used `assert mydata.b == 9` in their test, altering `data.b` should be directly reflected in `mydata.b`.